# How to use scala case to have multiple parameters?

Tags: scala, playframework, controller, playframework-2.0

I've just discovered last week Scala language, with the Play 2 Framework, and I'm a little confused..

I try to make a simple form with an username and a password with this tutorial :

http://www.jamesward.com/2012/02/21/play-framework-2-with-scala-anorm-json-coffeescript-jquery-heroku

but in the controller I have a function who doesn't work :

```
def addUser() = Action { implicit request =>
  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    {
      case (username) =>
        User.create(User(NotAssigned, username, password))
        Redirect(routes.Application.index())
    }
  )
}
```

It returns : not found: value password

And if i put password in the case, it does'nt wook too..

Any idea ?

Application.scala :

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{single, nonEmptyText}
import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import anorm.NotAssigned

import models.User

object Application extends Controller {

  val userForm = Form {
    tuple(
      "username" -> nonEmptyText,
      "password" -> nonEmptyText
    )
  }

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index(userForm))
  } 

  def addUser() = Action { implicit request =>
    userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => BadRequest,
      {
        case (username, password) =>
          User.create(User(NotAssigned, username, password))
          Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
    )
  }
}
```

User.scala :

```
package models

import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current

import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._

case class User(id: Pk[Long], username: String, password: String)

object User {

  val simple = {
    get[Pk[Long]]("id") ~
    get[String]("username") ~
    get[String]("password") map { 
      case username~password => User(id, username)
      case id~username => User(id, username)
    }
  }

  def findAll(): Seq[User] = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("SELECT * FROM user").as(User.simple *)
    }
  }

  def create(user: User): Unit = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
      SQL("INSERT INTO user(username, password) VALUES ({username}, {password})").on(
        'username -> user.username ,
        'password -> user.password
      ).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form you're binding should contain all the values you want to extract, i.e:

```
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms.{tuple,nonEmptyText}

val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "username" -> nonEmptyText, 
    "password" -> nonEmptyText
  )
)

def addUser() = Action { implicit request =>
  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    {
      case (username, password) => {
        User.create(User(NotAssigned, username, password))
        Redirect(routes.Application.index())
      }
    }
  )
}
```

In James's example the form contains just a single field, which will extract to a single value (in your case, username.) Using the "tuple" form mapping will allow you to get more values out.

Comment: It refers to the play.api.data.Forms.tuple mapping - I've added imports in the example.

Comment: it returns me : type mismatch; found : play.api.data.Form[(String, String)] required: play.api.data.Form[String]

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of fold() function is another function, which takes an object of Form class you're trying to bind to. In your case it would be an "userForm" object:

```
def addUser() = Action { implicit request =>
  userForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
    errors => BadRequest,
    okForm => { 
      // whatever you want
    }
  )
}
```

We don't know the type of your form. So difficult to say more. But, as for me, using "case" here is not a good idea.